# Passing slash '/' when routing to url

Tags: angular

I need to be able to send id when routing to page. The ID may contain slash '/', which will cause problem because the route will change.
Example : somepage/my-id/2f

I need to be able to read the id "my-id/2f" on the destination page.

I have tried to replace the '/' to %2F and also tried using encodeURIComponent, but the slash get converted to %252F on the router.

Below is the code that i used:

```
this.zone.run(()=>this._router.navigate(['../somepage/edit/'+value,{ relativeTo: this.route }));
```

Comment: Have you tried to use encodeURIComponent twice... Way back it worked for me in Angular JS. You can give it a try

Answer (score 0):

You can use btoa("myId/2f") for encoding it and using it in the route.
When you want to read it from the route just decode it with atob(/* hash from route */)

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
[routerLink]="['./', 'myId/2f']
```